# How to search string and highlight the searched strings in the Document

Tags: c#, winforms

> Hai, 
>     We are presently working on C# windows Application using
>   Janus Controls.
>           In that we have a search functionality like, if you search any word in search box, all the documents(it's my be Notepad,Ms-word,PDF)
>   which contains that searched word should be displayed in the
>   application.
>
> **when we Double click on the any document it should open a new window like popup
>   and show preview like what word you have searched and the searched
>   word should be highlighted with some color as like in our Microsoft
>   Word Document.**
>
> we can open the particular document using word or Pdf and highlight
>   the text. But we need to open it in one window and show all the
>   matched searched text in highlighted.
>          Please provide the possible Solution or link to work with or any tools to work with this scenario.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For including the documents from the system , you need to first include that document in the project either in the program or you can do it while creating the project . Then you need to open the file and read with the help of `StreamReader` and search for the particular word .

Comment: here searching is not a problem when i open the document using the Microsoft word. but here i want to load the that word content in another Windows form control and have to highlight the searched text.